# Open an accordion panel connected to jump link anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, materialize

Im using materializecss collapsible and trying to get an jump link to open an accordion panel and scroll to that link. I have the scrolling working, but I cant seem to get only the panel with id of the link target to open. Right now I just have the click opening all the accordion panels with css.

```
 $('.open_accordion[data-accordion]').on('click', function () {  
    let target = $(this).attr("href");
 $(".collapsible-body").css("display", "block")
 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f638pmk1/

I tried adding the active class to the li tag and the div tag with the collapsible-body class but it still doesnt open that section. I think I have the target in the variable, but not sure how to use it. Im down to using a pure JS way. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is pretty straightforward but I had to change a couple of things and also rebuild in Codepen (which I find much easier).

1) You need to add the ID to the collapsible header of the panel you are targeting and a class of scrollspy:

```
<li class="x-accordion-group">
      <div id="lee-open" class="collapsible-header scrollspy" id="linked">Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body x-accordion-toggle">
      ...
```

If you wanted to open a collapsible normally, you'd click the header - that's how they work.

2) [Initialize scrollspy](https://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html). Scrollspy is smooth scrolling in materializecss, you add matching ID and class of .scrollspy to the target div:

```
$('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
```

3) Force a click on the target element (the header of the collapsible):

```
$(target).trigger('click');
```

No need to add any css to the collapsible at all. Note, I added a class of active to the first collapsible (on the li), just to give us some space so actually scroll through.

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/ZEGLNvL